# Remove Globals from Nashorn

Tags: nashorn

Is there a way to remove access to globals in Nashorn short of

```
$ENV=undefined
```

?

I have done some searching, but I am unable to see anything other than how to use globals.

Also, is there a list of arguments/flags I can pass into the script engine?  I am currently doing --no-java, but I cannot find a comprehensive list anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of command-line options via `jjs -help`.

I don't know for sure about removing globals, but I doubt it. Nashorn uses a `Global` class that represents the ECMAScript `global` object, as described [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes).

> The default context's ENGINE_SCOPE is a wrapped instance of ECMAScript "global" object - which is the "this" in top level script expressions. So, you can access ECMAScript top-level objects like "Object", "Math", "RegExp", "undefined" from this scope object. Nashorn Global scope object is represented by an internal implementation class called jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.

That `Global` class has a bunch of the base ECMAScript plumbing baked into it in an immutable way, as without it javascript simply wouldn't work (no `Object` or `Function` prototypes, for instance). That page states that attempts to use an alternative object as the global will result in the engine placing your custom 'global' object into a new `Global` instance. Trying to run Javascript without that `global` plumbing simply wouldn't work.

Now if what you want to do is limit the Java classes available to a script, that's relatively straightforward (though not as straightforward as I wish it was).

```
ClassFilter filter = new ClassFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean exposeToScripts(String name) {
        // This would disable all Java classes
        return false;
    }
};
ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(filter);
```

The main downside here is that the `ClassFilter` and `getScriptEngine(ClassFilter)` methods aren't part of the `javax.scripting` API, and you have to access the Nashorn-specific classes in the `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting` package directly.